# Add DEFAULT to existing column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ddl, default-value

In Microsoft SQL server, how can I add/change the default on an existing table column using T-SQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD  CONSTRAINT constraintName  
   DEFAULT ('XYZ') FOR [YourColumn]
```

To change the default, drop the constraint and re-add it with the new value:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
DROP CONSTRAINT constraintName

ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD  CONSTRAINT constraintName  
   DEFAULT ('ABC') FOR [YourColumn]
```

Comment: Can also do it in the designer.